# How can I get two stacked chart.js charts to be different types?

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, chart.js

I have to chart.js charts that are stacked, and should be on the same x axis. How can I get the top one to be a bar chart, but the bottom one to be a line chart? I'm not sure of another way to declare 'type' other than at the top, where it affects all of the charts.

Here is an example stackbitz to the charts I'm building
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chartjs-multiple-charts?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Thanks so much!

Comment: You should take a look at the official documentation instead of some example. https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/mixed.html

Answer (score 0):

You have two individual charts, hence you should define a distinct `Chart.ChartConfiguration` for each. Provided that `Chart.ChartOptions` are the same for both charts, this could look as follows:

```
const chartOptions: Chart.ChartOptions = {
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  legend: { display: false },
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{ display: false }],
    yAxes: [{ display: false }],
  }
}

const chartConfigs: Chart.ChartConfiguration[] = [{
    type: 'bar',
    options: chartOptions
  },{
    type: 'line',
    options: chartOptions
}];
```

And inside `ngAfterViewInit`, you use `chartConfigs[index]` to pick the appropriate chart configuration.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.charts = this.chartElementRefs.map((chartElementRef, index) => {
    const config = Object.assign({}, chartConfigs[index], { data: this.chartData[index] });      
    return new Chart(chartElementRef.nativeElement, config);
  });
}
```

Please have a look at your amended [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chartjs-multiple-charts-epvi5x?file=src/app/app.component.ts)